# How to get FragmentManager from Application context?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-context, fragmentmanager

I have a LinearLayout, to call a BottomSheetDialogFragment as [in this example](http://www.androidauthority.com/bottom-sheets-707252/)

```
static class DemoUIView extends LinearLayout {

  DateView dateView;

  public DemoUIView(Context context){ // Constructor
    //..
    dateView.setOnClickListener(v-> {
      BottomSheetDialogFragment bottomSheetDialogFragment = new BottomSheet3DialogFragment();
      bottomSheetDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), bottomSheetDialogFragment.getTag());
    })
  }
}
```

But I can not access the FragmentManager there.. 
**How can I call the BottomSheetDialogFragment from there?**

EDIT Dagger 2.11 :

```
public class DemoApplication extends Application implements HasActivityInjector {

    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        DemoApplicationComponent appComponent = DaggerDemoApplicationComponent.builder()
                .application(this)
                .build()
    }

    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
        return activityInjector;
    }

}
```

and DemoApplicationComponent:

```
@ApplicationScope
@Component(
        modules = {
                ApplicationModule.class
        }
)
public interface DemoApplicationComponent extends IApplicationComponent {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);
        DemoApplicationComponent build();
    }
}
```

and the corresponding interfaec:

```
public interface IApplicationComponent {
    Application getApplication();
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't call a BottomSheetDialogFragment or any other fragment from the view; The fragment can contain views, but the view cannot contain fragments. Try to show your BottomSheetDialogFragment from an activity or from other fragment. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Add it as `Constructor` parameter

```
private DateView dateView;
private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

public DemoUIView(Context context, FragmentManager mFragmentManager) { // Constructor
    //..
    this.mFragmentManager = mFragmentManager;
    dateView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        BottomSheetDialogFragment bottomSheetDialogFragment = new BottomSheet3DialogFragment();
        bottomSheetDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), bottomSheetDialogFragment.getTag());
    })
}
```

**Edit**

```
// use android.app.FragmentManager
FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((Activity)context).getFragmentManager();
// android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Comment: It is Dagger injected and I only have `Application context` to call DemoUIView(Application context)

Comment: You can try again.@RalfWickum

Comment: What du you mean?!

Comment: Use the way to get `FragmentManager` .

Comment: Yeah tell me. Application does not deliver it

Comment: You have `context` in your `Constructor` ,isn't you ?So you can get `FragmentManager ` by using it .

Comment: ```Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.demo.DemoApplication cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity```

Comment: Done, see OP EDIT field

Comment: Good luck to you .